# Django POST not calling view

Tags: python, django, post, django-templates, view

I am trying to create a simple subscription form in the front page of my site. I created the view with a model form (the model contains only name and e-mail as attributes). When I go to the root address (GET) it works fine and loads the form. I then fill it with some data, click the submit button (the form action can either be set to '' or '/', the result is the same) and it redirects to the same root page, but it does not load anything, the page remains blank. In the console I can see it calling through POST method, but not even the first print of the view function gets printed.

Any ideas? I know it must be something silly, but I spent sometime in it and haven't yet found out what it could be.

In urls.py:

```
url(r'', FrontPage.as_view(template_name='rootsite/frontpage.html')),
```

In rootsite/views.py

```
class FrontPage(TemplateView):
    '''
    Front (index) page of the app, so that users can subscribe to
    have create their own instance of the app
    '''

    template_name = 'rootsite/frontpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, 
                         *args, 
                         **kwargs):

        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(self.request))
        print self.request.method
        if self.request.method is 'POST':
            print 'OK - POST IT IS, FINALLY'
            form = NewUsersForm(self.request.POST)
            print form.__dict__
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + '?thanks=1')
         else:
            form = NewUsersForm()

        return {'form':form}
```

Comment: maybe It's because of templateview ! do you have this problem with other class base views?

Comment: also you call twice the `template_name` ; once in the `views.py` once in `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a redirect from within get_context_data - it's for context data only, hence the name.

You should really be using a proper [form view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) for this, which includes methods for redirecting after form validation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a csrf_token in your template (as per the example here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html)?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I could be wrong, but I thought Django wouldn't accept a POST request without a csrf token?

Comment: I am using crispy forms to render the forms.
Nevertheless, this solution did not solve the problem. But thanks.